# What is the purpose of that HTML file in the .sikuli directory?

Tags: sikuli

When I create a new .sikuli file, for example `Dummy.sikuli`. 
It will create a `Dummy.py` and a `Dummy.html` file in this `.sikuli` directory.

If I add new code to `Dummy.py`, it automaticly updates the `Dummy.html` as well. 
But what exactly is the purpose of that `html file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This html file is only created when you save a script using Sikuli IDE. Originally the intention was so that users can share their scripts on the web (have a look [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/devs/system-design.html#the-structure-of-a-sikuli-source-executable-script-sikuli-skl)). Not sure if many users do that however.

Comment: So I have a HTML file to share my code online. 
Thanks for the answer, you are right about me not doing that. 
If I want my software to become open-source I will offer the complete program for download. haha